# How to fix "Cannot autowire service: Argument references class but no such service exists" in Sylius?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

In Sylius 1.11, after creating a new `Campaign` entity using the maker bundle, I get this error when trying to fetch a campaign using its repository:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\CampaignRepository": argument "$class" of method "Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct()" references class "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata" but no such service exists.

This seems to be the code that trigger the error:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\CampaignRepository;

class CampaignController extends AbstractController {
    protected CampaignRepository $repository;

    public function __construct(CampaignRepository $repository) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function details(string $id)
    {
        $campaign = $this->repository->find($id);

        dd($campaign);
    }
}
```

The `App\Repository\CampaignRepository` exists and is defined as follow, which is what [the Sylius documentation recommends](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html#change-repository-to-extend-entityrepository):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Campaign;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Campaign>
 *
 * @method Campaign|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Campaign|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Campaign[]    findAll()
 * @method Campaign[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CampaignRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

It turns out Sylius is quite picky on both the type hinting and the variable name. This is due to how Symfony's dependency injection works and how Sylius chose to use it.

Change the constructor to:

```php
public function __construct(
   \Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface $campaignRepository
) {
    $this->repository = $campaignRepository;
}
```

## How are you supposed to guess that?

You need to use the `bin/console debug:container` command. But if you try, you'll run into the same error message as when running you controller action.

What you need to do is:

1. comment any method that use the symfony's dependency injection feature to access an instance of your repository (in our case the `App\Controller\CampaignController::__construct()` method)
2. run the `bin/console debug:container CampaignRepository`
   This will return you a list of services:

```bash
bin/console debug:container CampaignRepository

Select one of the following services to display its information:
[0] App\Repository\CampaignRepository
[1] Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository $campaignRepository
[2] Doctrine\Common\Collections\Selectable $campaignRepository
[3] Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface $campaignRepository
[4] Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $campaignRepository
[5] Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $campaignRepository
```

3. chose a combination of class name & parameter to use as your constructor parameter (I went with `Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface $campaignRepository` but any of the suggestions with a parameter name should work)
4. uncomment the method you commented on step 1 & update its signature
5. voilà

If you're curious how this works, have a look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type

Comment: Did you happen to try having CampaignRepository extend ServiceEntityRepository?  Because that it what the original error message is complaining about.  Your App\Controller class is the only class using autowire.  The other services have some sort of explicit wiring going on.

Comment: I might add that the basic issue with your approach is that if you add additional methods to CampaignRepository then you won't be able to use the methods in your controller without the IDE complaining.

Comment: @Cerad The error message never mentions `ServiceEntityRepository`. I didn't try extending `ServiceEntityRepository ` because [the Sylius documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html#change-repository-to-extend-entityrepository) clearly state that you should extend `EntityRepository `.
If I do what you suggests, the error goes away, but it doesn't feel safe to disregard the docs.

Comment: As for code completion, decent IDEs let you override the detected type of a variable using a comment.
Example : `/** @var CampaignRepository $campaignRepository`

Comment: Interesting.  Your link does indeed change ServiceEntityRepository to EntityRepository.  Sylius must also do some additional tweaking because out of the box Symfony installs a ServiceEntityRepositoryFactory which pull repositories out of the service container.  So yes going with the documentation is probably the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

As a type-hint you can use any of the interfaces that the repository class implements, the base ones that can be used for any resource repository are `Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface` and `Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository`. For built-in Sylius resources, there are repository interfaces in the lower-level components and sometimes in the core component, like `Sylius\Component\Order\Repository\OrderRepositoryInterface` and `Sylius\Component\Core\Repository\OrderRepositoryInterface`.
Plugins usually also define interfaces.
For custom repositories in your projects, you should also define interfaces if you add custom methods.
The argument name also matters.
To check which type-hints are available, together with the argument name use the command `bin/console debug:autowiring campaing`.

Answer (score -1):

you can add to the file services.yaml

`your sercvice here -> the path of your file: autowire: true`
or add the arguments manually
`your sercvice here -> the path of your file: arguments:[....]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to manually wire arguments using symfony, but I don't know the value I need to wire for the `$class` argument, in this specific context.

Comment: "your sercvice here" - what do you mean by that? Adding the lines you've shared should trigger a hard error message